# Terraform Cloud: dynamic provider credentials and aliases

Tags: terraform, amazon-iam, openid-connect, terraform-provider-aws, terraform-cloud

Following this [example](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cloud-docs/workspaces/dynamic-provider-credentials/aws-configuration) from Hashicorp, I'm struggling to understand the right way to populate Aliases for AWS Providers.

Let's assume I've got 2 AWS Roles in 2 different accounts, OIDC is configured properly for Terraform Cloud to access them:

- `arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/test-terraform-cloud-access`
- `arn:aws:iam::123456789013:role/staging-terraform-cloud-access`

Now, following the documentation, I use:

- `TFC_AWS_PROVIDER_AUTH = true`
- `TFC_AWS_RUN_ROLE_ARN  = arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/test-terraform-cloud-access`

Now, based on their documentation, they advice using this config:

```
variable "tfc_aws_dynamic_credentials" {
  description = "Object containing AWS dynamic credentials configuration"
  type = object({
    default = object({
      shared_config_file = string
    })
    aliases = map(object({
      shared_config_file = string
    }))
  })
}
```

Then you can target the alias this way:

```
provider "aws" {
  shared_config_files = [var.tfc_aws_dynamic_credentials.default.shared_config_file]
}

provider "aws" {
  alias = "ALIAS1"
  shared_config_files = [var.tfc_aws_dynamic_credentials.aliases["ALIAS1"].shared_config_file]
}
```

My questions are:

- Where does this `shared_config_file` is configured in Terraform Cloud?
- How do I indicate my secondary role to use for this alias such as `["STAGING"]`?
- I was looking at the [vault example](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cloud-docs/workspaces/dynamic-provider-credentials/specifying-multiple-configurations), can I use something like `TFC_AWS_RUN_ROLE_ARN_STAGING` for this to work?

I did try the last one, but it doesn't seem to be picked up by the system.

Thanks a lot again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have multiple configurations for the `hashicorp/aws` provider that each need a separate dynamic credentials configuration then you must also consider the companion tutorial [Specifying Multiple Configurations](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cloud-docs/workspaces/dynamic-provider-credentials/specifying-multiple-configurations). The tutorial you linked in your question is focused on the simpler and more common case of using only a single set of dynamic credentials for each provider.

The tutorial describes setting additional environment variables where each has a suffix which will appear as the key in the `aliases` map.

In your case then, if you want to use the "staging" ARN for `ALIAS1` then you would set the environment variables as follows:

- `TFC_AWS_RUN_ROLE_ARN` to `arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/test-terraform-cloud-access`
- `TFC_AWS_RUN_ROLE_ARN_ALIAS1` to `arn:aws:iam::123456789013:role/staging-terraform-cloud-access`

With those two environment variables set, your `var.tfc_aws_dynamic_credentials` object should contain both the `default` object as before, referring to an AWS configuration file for the "test" role, and also have an `ALIAS1` key in `aliases` whose object refers to a separate AWS configuration file for the "staging" role.

A configuration like you wrote should then work:

```
variable "tfc_aws_dynamic_credentials" {
  description = "Object containing AWS dynamic credentials configuration"
  type = object({
    default = object({
      shared_config_file = string
    })
    aliases = map(object({
      shared_config_file = string
    }))
  })
}

provider "aws" {
  shared_config_files = [
    var.tfc_aws_dynamic_credentials.default.shared_config_file,
  ]
}

provider "aws" {
  # Notice that this "alias" doesn't need to match the one
  # in the environment variable. These are two separate
  # namespaces, so you can use the same names here if you
  # like but that's not actually required.
  alias = "staging"
  shared_config_files = [
    var.tfc_aws_dynamic_credentials.aliases["ALIAS1"].shared_config_file,
  ]
}
```

These `shared_config_file` arguments refer to AWS configuration files as described in the AWS docs [Shared `config` and `credentials` files](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkref/latest/guide/file-format.html). When you're using dynamic credentials, Terraform Cloud's execution environment creates those files dynamically just before running Terraform CLI, and then passes the paths to those files in as as part of the input variable `tfc_aws_dynamic_credentials`.

Those configuration files contain information about which role to assume and which JSON Web Token to use to authenticate to the AWS APIs. Therefore the file associated with `ALIAS1` will specify the staging role ARN, while the file associated with the "default" object will specify the testing role ARN.

Comment: Note that this question, being about a web service rather than about a programming language, might be considered off-topic for Stack Overflow. I've tried to answer it anyway, but if this answer isn't sufficient then it might be better to contact HashiCorp Support for help with this commercial product.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your complete answer and for the details on the mechanic of Terraform Cloud @martin-atkins, I'll give it a go on Monday and confirm that's working :)
I've actually been in touch with Hashicorp Support and linked them to this post, so it could also be good for them if they want to update the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @martin for your previous and complete answer.
One last important detail in order to have Aliases working properly in Terraform Cloud, you need to enable Alias in your environment too, i.e:

`TFC_AWS_PROVIDER_AUTH_ALIAS1 = true`

Alongside with `TFC_AWS_RUN_ROLE_ARN_ALIAS1` to `arn:aws:iam::123456789013:role/staging-terraform-cloud-access`

If you don't do that, `var.tfc_aws_dynamic_credentials.aliases` object will be left empty.